# Serial Communication in Cinder on Mac

Tags: serial-port, cinder

I'm using Cinder 0.8.6 on mac OSX 10.10. I am pulling in serial data via usb from an Arduino. The data is showing up fine in Arduino's serial monitor, but the Cinder SerialCommunication example is giving me:

```
Device: cu.usbmodem1451
Device: tty.usbmodem1451
Device: cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
Device: tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
Device: cu.Bluetooth-Modem
Device: tty.Bluetooth-Modem
There was an error initializing the serial device!
```

I'm wondering what next steps to take in order to troubleshoot this so that Cinder can collect the serial data coming in from the Arduino.

**UPDATE** I've found that if I close the arduino serial monitor, the Cinder SerialCommunication app loads, takes over the port, and I don't get the error, but it hangs immediately. The data coming in from the Arduino looks like this:

```
E2: D=3  V=13
E2: D=2  V=15
E2: D=3  V=18
E2: D=3  V=21
E3: D=-1  V=-1
E3: D=1  V=0
E3: D=-1  V=-1
E3: D=1  V=0
E3: D=-1  V=-1
E1: D=3  V=3
E1: D=3  V=6
E1: D=4  V=10
E1: D=4  V=14
E1: D=5  V=19
E1: D=6  V=25
```

Comment: So ... what are you trying to achieve? What is the problem?

Comment: I made an edit to my last sentence expanding on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like your Arduino:

```
Device: cu.usbmodem1451
Device: tty.usbmodem1451
```

You may need to tweak this section in the sample's setup function:

```
Serial::Device dev = Serial::findDeviceByNameContains( "tty.usbserial" );
```

to be something like this:

```
Serial::Device dev = Serial::findDeviceByNameContains( "tty.usbmodem" );
```

e.g.

```
try {
        Serial::Device dev = Serial::findDeviceByNameContains( "tty.usbmodem" );
        mSerial = Serial::create( dev, 9600 );
    }
    catch( SerialExc &exc ) {
        CI_LOG_EXCEPTION( "coult not initialize the serial device", exc );
        exit( -1 );
    }
```

Alternatively you could explicitly use the full path:

```
Serial::findDeviceByName("tty.usbmodem1451");
```

but this may be less flexible since the digits after "tty.usbmodem" may change if you use a different USB port on OSX.

Comment: Okay, I've found that if I close the arduino serial monitor, the Cinder SerialCommunication app loads, takes over the port, and I don't get the error, but it hangs immediately.

Comment: Yes, you can only have one connection at a time per device. If Serial Monitor is open you can't use the Serial connection from other other applications and vice-versa.